# Including Javascript file in CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I have read all the topics "Including Javascript files in CodeIgniter" but these don't work for me! 
I reduced my problem to the following code.

I work with WAMP and I copied Codeigniter in `c:\wamp\www\codeigniter` folder.

In `c:\wamp\www\codeigniter\application\controlers\` I have a file `mnd3c_test.php` that contains:

```
<?php
class mnd3c_test extends CI_Controller {
public function __construct()
  {parent::__construct();}
public function test()
  {$this->load->view('mnd3v/mnd3v_test.php'); }
}
```

In `c:\wamp\www\codeigniter\application\view\mnd3v\` I have a file `mnd3v_test.php` that contains:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mnd3js.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
<h3 onclick="fsort()">Click on me to see alert message</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

In `c:\wamp\www\codeigniter\application\view\mnd3v\` I also have a file `mnd3js.js` that contains:

```
function fsort()
{  alert ("fsort"); }
```

I have set in config.php:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeigniter/';
```

I load my page in Internet Explorer or Google Chrome with:

```
http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/mnd3c_test/test
```

and when I click on "Click on me to see alert message" nothing happens (In IE I have a "Error on page" message). I have tried to put in src atribute all kind of values, like `mnd3v/mnd3js.js` or `localhost/application/views/mnd3v/mnd3js.js` but nothing happend.

I would like to see the alert message. Can anybody help me?

Comment: The path to your JavaScript file is wrong.  Where is your `index.php` file located?  If your `src` URL is simply `mnd3js.js`, then it would need to be located in same directory as your `index.php`.

Comment: index.php file is located in codeigniter folder. I put mnd3js.js in codeigniter folder but nothing happen. In fact I put mnd3js.js in many folders, but I didn't see the alert message.

Comment: All I can tell you is if your `src` path is simply `mnd3js.js`, then it would need to be located in *same* directory as your `index.php`.  What troubleshooting have you performed?  Have you inspected your JavaScript console errors?  Are you sure you spelled the file name correctly?

Comment: *"I put `mnd3js.js` in many folders"* ~ If you insist on programming by "trial & error" rather than by logic & knowledge, you might as well copy the file into all folders at once.  If it works, delete them one by one until it breaks again.  Hopefully, you'll learn something along the way.

Comment: The name is ok. I don't know how to inspect my code with JavaScript console.

Comment: If you don't know how to use the JavaScript console built into every browser, then start by researching and learning this most basic task.  Here is Chrome's:  https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console

Comment: JavaScript Console give me the following error:

Comment: http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/mnd3c_test/mnd3js.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
I had somehow expected this error because I thought that Codeigniter uses the URL like a Control URL - but mnd3js.js isn't the name of a function in the control class.

Comment: Now you've learned something critical information.  Whatever `src` you used is mapping to the URL in the error message.

Comment: Maybe I miss to set some configuration in CodeIgniter.

Comment: Put your `js` file in that location from the error message OR fix your `src`.

Comment: The error message doesn't give me a location, because mnd3c_test isn't a folder - it is a file located in codeigniter\application\controllers\ folder !

Comment: I've never had this issue.  Sounds like you need to reexamine everything to verify proper settings.   If it were mine, I'd use an absolute URL.

Comment: It doesn't work with an absolute URL, i have tried before. It seems that the URL is interpreted by index.php, and it is expected its url format (index.php/controller/controller_method)

Comment: Funny, I use absolute URLs on all of my CodeIgniter projects without issue.

Comment: Thank you Sparky for spending a lot of time with me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using WAMP, CodeIgniter, JavaScript, if you need to include JavaScript file in a view file with src attribute, you have to put js file outside the application folder. If the src address points to a subfolder of codeigniter application folder, CodeIgniter doesn't know to interpret this address. Why, I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to include the javascript file into the views folder.  In fact I would say this is actually a bad idea, since the view folder in Codeigniter is meant to hold php files which are kind of like a templates.

Instead consider putting javascript or other loadable media in their own folder outside of Codeigniter.  Simply create a folder called `js` off of your root (it's probably the same level as the `application` folder).  Then just reference the files using relative links

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/mnd3js.js" ></script>`

or with an absolute link

`<script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>js/jquery.js"></script>`

I prefer relative links myself, but ultimately it depends on your application.

Comment: Unless you have compelling reason not to, you should always err on the side of including the base_url.

Comment: I wanted to put my JavaScript file inside the codeigniter application folder because this code was developped for this aplication, and only the javascript code bring from other sources, such JQuery for example, is appropriate to stay outside the application folder. But this isn't a problem, I can put anywhere my JavaScript code if it works!

Answer (score 0):

I do this way `<script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>js/jquery.js"></script>` where js source exist in my public path

Comment: Thank you, your answer help me to discover the source of my problems!